# What's the best way to share a Zotero collection (without creating a new "group" collection)

Tags: citations, reference-managers

I've got a large Zotero library split into several large collections. I know that I'm able to share collections by creating a group in Zotero and then creating a collection within that group. Is it possible to share a pre-existing collection, though?

Alternatively, can I synchronize a collection in a group with a collection that is already in my local library? Sharing a collection within a group is great, but if that collection starts off as a copy of a collection I already have in my Zotero then I'm going to have to maintain two collections independently.

Comment: Might get a better answer on the Zotero forum!

Comment: Thanks, I've asked my questions here: https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/52185/whats-the-best-way-to-share-a-zotero-collection-without-creating-a-new-group-collection/ -- will add any answer back here!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about a specific application, not academia.

Comment: Where can I find the guidelines for what questions should and shouldn't be asked on this forum, please?

Comment: @Jim The [help page](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) has general guidelines, but would probably not help in this case: this falls into a grey area at the boundary of questions that should or shouldn't be asked here.  If you are looking for further clarification, you can ask a question on [meta](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

The following was posted in response to [the OP's question on the Zotero forums](https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/52185/whats-the-best-way-to-share-a-zotero-collection-without-creating-a-new-group-collection/):

> [adamsmith](https://forums.zotero.org/account/2433/) Sep 14th 2015
>
> Easier sharing of parts of your library is planned, but currently, unfortunately, the answer to all of your questions is no. The only way to share a collection is to drag it into a group and it won't sync with the original collection.